# динамическое добавление уникальных options в select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ситуация следующая. Есть массив объектов (маркеры для карты). нужно сделать три, появляющихся друг за другом по мере выбора в каждом, выпадающих списка:

1. Район,
2. Округ,
3. Адреса...

все сделал, но не могу разобраться, как поставить проверку, чтобы в списках не было повторяющихся элементов.

```js
function onchange_sel_ao() {
  var aoSelObj = document.getElementById('sel_ao');
  var mo_container = document.getElementById('mo_container');
  var next_sel = document.getElementById('next_sel');
  var current_ao = aoSelObj.value;
  if (current_ao == "") {
    mo_container.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    var sel_mo = document.getElementById('sel_mo');
    var devElm = sel_mo.options;
    for (var i = sel_mo.options.length - 1; i > 0; i--) devElm.remove(i);
    var markersLen = markers.length;
    var moSelLen = sel_mo.length;
    for (var j = 0; j < markersLen; j++) {
      var t = markers[j];
      //  var arr = jQuery('[name=mo] > option').toArray();
      if (current_ao == t.properties.ao)
        sel_mo.options[moSelLen++] = new Option(t.properties.mo, t.properties.mo);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="sel_ao" name="ao" onchange="onchange_sel_ao();">
  <option selected disabled hidden>Выберите округ</option>
  <option value="Центральный">Центральный</option>
  <option value="Западный">Западный</option>
  <option value="Юго-Западный">Юго-Западный</option>
  <option value="Южный">Южный</option>
  <option value="Юго-Восточный">Юго-Восточный</option>
  <option value="Восточный">Восточный</option>
  <option value="Северо-Восточный">Северо-Восточный</option>
  <option value="Северный">Северный</option>
  <option value="Северо-Западный">Северо-Западный</option>
</select>
<div id="mo_container">
  <select id="sel_mo" name="mo" onchange="onchange_sel_mo();">
    <option selected disabled hidden>Выберите район</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="marker_container">
  <select id="sel_marker" name="marker" onchange="onchange_sel_marker(this);">
    <option selected disabled hidden>Выберите объект</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Буду невероятно признателен, если подскажите как реализовать проверку, а так же укажите на "косяки" в коде, так как я только начал обучение в этом направлении...

P.S. извините, если кому-то поломал глаза своим корявым кодом=)

Comment: уникальность можно проверить например подгрузив библиотеку lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#uniq

Comment: А откуда вы берете список?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, из массива объектов.  `var markers = [{
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "address": "...",
                    "mo": "Арбат",
                    "ao": "Центральный"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [37.597890,55.752151]
                }
            },`  "ao" - округ, "mo" - район, для второго выпадающего списка

Comment: Массив объектов жестко забит в код?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, к сожалению, да)

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, спасибо за совет, очень хорошая библиотека! жаль, что раньше не слышал о ней, сэкономил бы уйму времени и сил.

Comment: Ну так тогда потратьте полчаса своего времени и вычистите руками массив от дубликатов

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, на карте 94 маркера, у каждого уникальный адрес и координаты, а вот округ и район может совпадать...

Answer (score 0):

Простите, не до конца понял поставленной задачи из имеющегося описания, но могу дать совет, что удобно добавлять новые элементы и отслеживать дубликаты можно через прокси-массив с данными:

```
let container=$('#select'),
selects=new Proxy([],{
  set(array,key,value,proxy){
    if(array.includes(value)) return
    array[key]=value
    $('<option>',{value}).text(value).appendTo(container)
  }
})
selects.push('Район')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8u73xtrp/13/